# Generate button in dataTables from column value

Tags: javascript, php

I use datatable to render column and rows fron a json.
data variable is the json.

```
            "columns" : [
                { "data" : "id" },
                { "data" : "username" },
                { "data" : "email" },
                { "data" : "site" },
                { "data" : "author_name" },
                { "data" : "user_name" },
                { "data" : "city" },
                { "data" : "region" },
                { "data" : "added" },
                { "data" : "member_status" },
                { "data" : "its_username" },
                { "data" : "register_date" },
                {"defaultContent": "<a href='/admin/edit_recruited_user/' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a><a href='/admin/delete_recruited_user/' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"}
            ],
```

I am trying to add the value from id to my link `/admin/edit_recruited_user/`

Have any ideea if i can achieve this or i should rethink the datatables code ?

Comment: If you are referring to the link inside defaultContent, you will need to modify it while you build the JSON. If you can't, you'll have to build the contents in your PHP file.

Comment: I think i will amend the json as it`s the easiest way until now

Answer (score 0):

Add `columnDefs`.

See documentation https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1u28t', function(json) {
    $('#example').DataTable({
       data : json.data,
       columns : [
           { data : 'Id' },
           { data : 'Name' },
           { data : 'Alias' }
      ],
      columnDefs: [ {
       "targets": 0,
       "data": "download_link",
       "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
         return '<a href="/admin/edit_recruited_user/" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a><a href="/admin/delete_recruited_user/" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
       }
     }]
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example"/>
```